# Opposite of 'taking baby steps'

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

I already have giant steps / huge strides

in the context of

'Having previously taken tentative, half-hearted baby-steps Sophia began taking -------- towards attaining her life's ambitions'.

Comment: "biting off more than you can chew"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Giant strides**

See [Cambridge Dictionary online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/giant-stride) for examples of usage in this context, generally by British parliamentarians, e.g.

> ”Is this not a **giant stride** towards a nationwide capital-owning
>   democracy?”

This to me is the most natural opposite to “baby steps”. “Strides” seems to me more idiomatic than the “leaps” suggested in another answer. Certainly a comparison of the terms using the [Google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=giant+leaps%2C+giant+strides&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgiant%20leaps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgiant%20strides%3B%2Cc0)shows “giant strides” to have a longer history of usage, and even today is much more common.

A stride is a large step, whereas a leap entails taking both feet off the ground and often has the implication of jumping over something. The idiom here is [“**leaps and bounds**”](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/leaps-and-bounds). To use this I would recast the sentence a little:

> “Sophia began moving towards attaining her life’s ambitions **in leaps and
>   bounds”**.

Comment: An even better collocation is [great strides](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great+strides%2Cgiant+strides&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cgreat%20strides%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgreat%20strides%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGreat%20strides%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgiant%20strides%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgiant%20strides%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGiant%20strides%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Hellion — For me “great” grates rather. (Unless it’s Alexander).

Comment: Love 'leaps and bounds' - exactly the phrase I was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 4):

> Having previously taken tentative, half-hearted baby steps, Sophia began making *giant leaps* toward attaining her life's ambitions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible choices depending on what you want to express.

For example, are you interested in expressing that she is now confident?
- firm steps
- confident steps
- assertive actions

Or that she is now unduly incautious?
- overly confident steps
- unguarded steps

Or possibly that she is now making mistakes she previously didn't?
- unchecked steps
- risky steps
- foolhardy steps
- slapdash actions

Or that she is now competent at her actions?
- well placed steps
- efficient steps
- accurate steps